# Typescript keyof - how to use the value in a declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to use `keyof` to enforce type safety in an existing JS library (so I can't redefine any function calls). The class wraps a data structure, with `get` and `set` functions, like so:

```
declare class Component<T> {

    set(data: T);
    get(key: keyof T);

}
```

So far so good! But now I want to add an observer, using the same `keyof` functionality I'm using in `get`. Its second parameter is a callback, which is given the new and old values of the key provided. I've tried creating it like so:

```
type Callback<T, K extends keyof T> = (newValue: T[K], oldValue: T[K]) => void;

declare class Component<T> {
    observe(key: keyof T, cb: Callback<T, key>)
}
```

But TypeScript is rejecting my use of `key` in the `observe` function, saying

> cannot find name 'key'

Is there any way for me to get around this limitation right now? I can do this:

```
observe<K extends keyof T>(key: keyof T, cb: Callback<T,K>)
```

and it works fine, but that means my actual code is:

```
thing.observe<"key">("key", (newValue, oldValue) => {})
```

which just looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
type Callback<T, K extends keyof T> = (newValue: T[K], oldValue: T[K]) => void;

declare class Component<T> {
    observe<K extends keyof T>(key: K, cb: Callback<T, K>);
}

// example class
class XClass extends Component<{ name: string; value: number; }> { 
    testFn(): void { 
        // here the first argument needs to be a name of a T property
        // newValue and oldValue will be the same type of this property
        this.observe("name", (newValue, oldValue) => { });
    }
}
```